# Modular mixing table with balanced internal bus: is this a proper way to do it?

Tags: audio, design

**TL; DR:** Is the schematic below seem like a proper way of building a mixing console with differential internal bus?

---

I always wanted to have a mixing console but I want to do it the maker way: build one from scratch, using my own design. And for my own design, I want to make it modular, that is, every input channel is its own module that is pluggable to the system.

This means that I need an extensible internal bus design. I happen to run across a seller discounting on DE-9 connectors and I grabbed a bunch of them. I am thinking about designing those into the system, since I have lots of them now.

Pinout on the DE-9, which is also the 9 lines for the internal audio bus of this modular system:

1. `V+` (5V, max rating: 3A, linearly regulated, used by both analog and digital circuitry)
2. `V-` (-5V, max rating: 3A, linearly regulated, used only by analog circuitry)
3. `D-`
4. `R-`
5. `L-`
6. `GND` (Shorted to the chassis and shielding of the cable at the device)
7. `D+`
8. `R+`
9. `L+`

The `R+/-` and `L+/-` are two differential analog lines (balanced lines) sending an audio signal. `D+/-` are two digital communication lines that can be used by modules to talk with each other using some protocol.

Here is my questions in schematics:

### 1. Is this a proper linear regulator generating the 3 amperes maximum current ratings?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fns4xh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The two trimpots are set during testing to make sure this circuit regulates 5V with maximum current rating of 3A.

- Will the darlington-like arrangement of MOSFETs and BJTs bite me down the road? Is this essentially a LDO-like regulator using an IGBT-like pass element?
- How big of a transformer do I need?
- Is the 4700uF input filter cap enough?
- Do I actually need 3A? How to tell?

### 2. Can this two circuits work together, with multiple copies of circuit A driving copies of circuit B across the same set of bus lines?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyde6h.png)</sup>

Multiple copies of this channel input amplifier, driving...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ft2bbR.png)</sup>

... multiple copies of this output amplifier, with `L+/-` lines as buses. Am I going to get exactly this output for a set of input:

$$
V_{out} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}2k_iV_{i}
$$

at every output module, assuming that the bus traces are thick enough? Or can I only achieve this with exactly one output amplifier per bus?

### 3. What is the best protocol to use on this `D+/-` lines?

The protocol in question need to allow multiple microcontrollers talk with each other without manual address configuration. The lines need not to be differential, as the `D+/-` designation is merely following the form of `R+/-`, `L+/-` and `V+/-`.

- Will digital communications across this line cause trouble in audio?
- Can I avoid such troubles by making devices talking to each other in a baud rate high enough to be outside the audio range?

### 4. If I need to run this internal bus for a long run (e.g. a few meters), what should I do?

- What kind of care do I have to take?
- What kind of cabling should I use? Can I run this over some common medium for differential signaling, for example unshielded Cat5e or Cat6? Will this unshielded cable affect sound quality?
- Assuming the remote location use less power than Cat6 is capable of, which power rail should be omitted when sent over the cable since Cat6 have 8 conductors instead of 9? Is omitting `GND` a good choice and recover it at the remote location using this circuitry:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcqcg0.png)</sup>

### 5. Using different op amps in the system

The dual op amp chip used in the power supply is not considered here.

- Can I use different op amps in the system without redesigning the board? (If so, by socketing the chips, )
- Can I mix and match op amps of different series in the system (same series op amp per module, but different op amps across different modules)
- Can I mix and match op amps of different series in one module?
- Is this a reasonable op amp series designation:

  - `OPA2134`/`OPA4134`
  - `TL072`/`TL074`
  - `NE5532`/`NE5534`
  - `TL082`/`TL084`
  - `NJM4559` (dual amp chip only, quad amp version constructed using a daughterboard with two SMT chips if otherwise board design need not be changed)
  - `LM358`/`LM324`

Comment: (a) why not use COTS high-frequency switching regulators for the power, possibly in an external brick? (b) digital protocol will depend on choice of uC, but CAN is most robust and RS-485 not a bad choice. Depending on the topology having USB might be a good idea.

Comment: @pjc50 (a) If a COTS high frequency SMPS can cost less than this linear mains regulator I will use it. It is all cost driven. (b) The digital bus should allow bidirectional communication between uC's since every module will have one. It need to be multidrop. I can use topologies like half duplex UART over CAN PHY or the like.

Comment: @pjc50 Also about a SMPS, it must not throw off audio quality.

Comment: This question is way too big.

Comment: @MattYoung Kind of. Four big points and several questions under every point actually. But this is one concrete system so I asked all in one question.

Comment: This is exactly why we discourage broad, open-ended design review questions here on EE.SE: The answer(s) tend to become long strings of unrelated edits and/or comments. While this might help you with your immediate problems, it is of no value to the site overall. We DO allow design review questions in which you explain your choices and then focus on a few points about which you still have doubts. To get a better feel of what is or is not acceptable, search for "design review" on the [meta site](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @DaveTweed So your suggestion is rearrange this question into multiple bite-sized questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point nr.1 circuit won't work, you have problems in the output stage.

Point nr.2 (top): L+ is always zero (actually noise)

Point nr.4: does nothing.

You should simulate the circuits.

EDIT: circuit 1 was corrected, but I would not use a FET unless it is a logic level FET. In this case loose the bipolar and find a strong enough logic level FET and drive it directly.

1. This is not a LDO. But using a PMOS will allow you to make a LDO. LDOs can be tricky to stabilise.
2. How is the cooling of the circuit?
3. you need a transformer that can supply 2x 3A and a voltage giher than the drop on the output stage + 5V + 2V.
4. Depends on the frequency of the AC on transformer primary.
5. You are the designer. You are the only one that can chaeck how much current the mixer will draw.

EDIT: circuit 2 (top) corrected.

> The problem is now circuit 2 (bottom). Output is always 0V (noise).

***My mistake***. The OA3 output = +L - (-L) = 2*L

EDIT: The transformer + input rectifier is NOK. The diodes are not evenly loaded, some are even OFF all the time.

EDIT: rectifier stage in circuit 1 corrected, looks OK now.

EDIT: I see no point in splitting the signal into two out of phase signals, mixing them and then reconstructing the signal again. You could simply add them.

EDIT: Splitting the signal into a differential pair will probably won't help when the driving impedance is 10kOhm. This technique also works only if you have the same disturbance on both cables (so common mode). Differential disturbances will still have an easy access into such a system. Professional audio systems have a 600 Ohm impedance and are shielded.

Comment: Corrected again. I don't have a good enough simulation software actually. Point 4 is about recovering the lost in transmission GND rail.

Comment: Also nobody manufactures a strong enough logic level power PMOS so I have to use a small PMOS and a big NPN BJT in this Darlington-like arrangement. So might as well do it symmetrically.

Comment: Use LT spice - this one works. What you will be lacking is models for your devices, but those can be modelled by hand pretty easily.

Comment: Will LTspice run under OS X smoothly? I tried both Proteus and NI Multisim under a virtual machine but the performance of VMware Fusion always bite me even with VT-x on.

Comment: I don't know, but there is a version for osX. Just try it.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It seem to me that you still did not read through the modified schematics.

Comment: Can't see, is one a PMOS and the other NMOS?

Comment: Yup, complementary PMOS and NMOS, complementary power NPN and PNP. I also changed the point 2 schematic.

Comment: Also the point 4 schematic do not have the GND rail at its input - the Cat6 is one conductor short so V+ and V- are carried over using one pair in the cable and something have to be there to recover the GND rail.

Comment: Uhh why point 2 bottom schematic is wrong? The two op amps OA1 and OA2 sum L+ and L- bus respectively, and the third op amp takes the difference of the sums, which is generated in the first place as \$+2k_iV_i\$ and \$-2k_iV_i\$

Comment: About the power supply, it is taking 240V/50Hz mains input.

Comment: I made a mistake. See edit. Point nr.2 (bottom) is fine.

Comment: Saw it. So if I need the \$V_{out}=2\sum^{n}_{i=1}2k_iV_i\$ I need to get rid of the gain 2 amplifier in the input then? Can I do so by just getting rid of the op amp, or a buffer is still required?

Comment: Uhh why the two bridge rectifiers not okay? How should I do it then?

Comment: I lost you. Circuit nr.2 simply amplifys Left chanell by a factor of 2. I fail to see this as mixing.

Comment: Updated the regulator again. I have written that circuit Nr. 2 are multiple copies of top and bottom circuits sharing the `L+/-` buses. Mixing is happening when bus lines are shared.

Comment: So if I understand correctly you would join multiple +L1, +L2,...+Ln and thus achieve mixing with the bottom circuit 2? Same for -Ln?

Comment: Yes. There is only one set of `L+/-` lines across the system and every input amplifier is sending signal to this set of bus lines.

Comment: See edit above.

Comment: That do have a point, but as I asked above I do need to run the bus for longer runs from time to time, and using differential signalling is also my way of tackling the interference issue without using some crazyness like coax on board. Also, a balanced internal bus does make taking balanced XLR audio inputs easier.

Comment: The schematic above is more like a concept. My internal drive impedance will probably be somewhere like 51 ohms, roughly matching that of a Cat6 cable.